# HTML Form Variable: 2D array on PHP and Rails Difference

Tags: php, html, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I've been coding on Ruby on Rails in the past 3 months and  now I'm switching back to PHP. I've got little bit curious when I realized that on RoR you can create 2D form variable like this

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="persons[][name]">
  <input type="text" name="persons[][address]">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="persons[][name]">
  <input type="text" name="persons[][address]">
</div>
```

which results on making an array of persons which have name and address property each.

BUT, on PHP the first index can not be empty. Instead i must do it like this

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="persons[0][name]">
  <input type="text" name="persons[0][address]">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" name="persons[1][name]">
  <input type="text" name="persons[1][address]">
</div>
```

Its not convenient when it comes to dynamic forms, when user can add not determined number of persons. I must use javascript to maintain the index on PHP.

**Question**: Why this difference exist? What makes this difference? Is this a language feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not really a language question but rather a framework question - there is no actual standards for how form name attributes should map to data structures - the pattern of using square bracket syntax to map names to hashes or array dates back to the early web frameworks.

Note how I said that it's a framework question; PHP is not just a language - it's got many parts of a web framework of varying quality bolted on to the core of language such as the way that it automatically parses the query string and the request body into the `$_GET` and `$_POST` superglobals (and the extreme facepalm that was `register_globals`).

I believe the reason PHP does not parse `persons[][name]` into:

```
array(
  array(
    array(
      "name" => "foo" 
    )
  )
)
```

Is due to the quirks of PHP arrays - an array in PHP is a truly strange beast indeed which is actually an ordered map - so a "one dimensional array" in PHP is actually:

```
array(
 0 => 'A',
 1 => 'B',
 2 => 'C'
)
```

Which makes it simpler to parse `persons[0][name]`.

Comment: I have given up trying to find logical design in PHP - it's just a design by laziness language. If it works it works - otherwise we just toss some more gluecode on top.